# Using Scala how to find out if a list of chars are present in a String, where there are duplicate characters?

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections

Consider the following example , I have a given set of **words** and a given set of **chars** . I have to find out if there is a word which can be made from the list of chars while respecting duplication - i.e. the word is a multiset subset of the multiset of chars. Thus for chars `List('a', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's')`, word `"apqsrr"` is not a valid solution since it contains two `'r'`s. The usual solution that I can think of is to iterate over chars of a word and if a match is found in chars then remove that char from chars list. This can handle duplicates but I don't know how to write this in scala in a more **functional way**.

From what knowledge I have of scala I was able to write the following code, which works fine if there are no duplicate letters.

```
val words = List("apqsrr", "avadavat", "avail", "availability", "available", 
  "avalanche", "avantgarde", "avarice")
val chars = List('a', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's')

for (w <- words if w.forall(chars.contains)) yield w

// another way 
words.find(_.forall(chars.contains))
```

Comment: Can you clarify "can be made from exactly"? Do you mean that if the list of `Char`s contains extra letters this is invalid? I ask this because your own solution leaves it as valid to have extra `Char`s.

Comment: It means if your word contains extra chars like s then your chars also should have that many number of s chars . ie. Each char from word should be present in list of chars plus if there are duplicate letters in words then same should be also present in chars.

Comment: That's not my question ... I'm asking *can the list of `Char`s have additional `Char`s*. You said "exactly" but then your code is basically checking if the list is a multiset subset of the word.

Comment: For example if the word is "a" and the list is `List('a', 'b')` should that be valid or invalid?

Comment: Yes it is valid . Basically you have to create a valid word from a list of chars , imagine picking up one char at a time from a bag, so if you word contains double a and you have only single a in your bag then you can not complete the word.  And my solution is not correct that is what I have mentioned above, it only works for non dupes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> words.find(_.diff(chars).isEmpty)
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> val chars = List('a','p','q','r','s','r') // Added another 'r'
chars: List[Char] = List(a, p, q, r, s, r)

scala> words.find(_.diff(chars).isEmpty)
res1: Option[String] = Some(apqsrr)
```

Comment: Perfect !! I never knew there was a diff api of scala . Thanks